# Javscript store data from json file into map?

Tags: javascript, java, json

I´m quite new to Javascript, but know a lot about Java. Im trying to learn the basics by doing little projects, for understanding the language and code. In Java, i worked a lot with storing data from maps in json-files and, when you start the programm, the json file loads the data into the map.

An example for Java:

```
public Map<Integer, Client> example = new HashMap<>();
```

Herefor the Client class :

```
public class Client {

private String username;
private String password;
private String host;

public Client(String username, String password, String host) {
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
    this.host = host;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public String getHost() {
    return host;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}
}
```

I want to do the same thing, but now in Javascript. My map looks like that:

```
var price= new Map();
```

Like the Java example above, I want to load such a Map into a json file and want to load the data from the json file into my map.

Could somebody proivde me with a good example of code, how to store data from json in my map ? Even a link for a tutorial would be great!

Comment: Java is not JavaScript. Knowledge in one will not always transfer to the other. I know you’re not actually saying they are, but it’s worth restating.

Comment: @evolutionxbox I know, thats the reason why I ask ?

Comment: sorry I clarified that you weren’t saying that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JS it's more common to use plain objects instead of `Map()`.
For example, let's say you have the same `Client` class:

```
class Client {
    constructor(username, password, host) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.host = host;
    }
}

const client1 = new Client('username1', 'password1', 'localhost');
const client2 = new Client('username2', 'password2', 'localhost');
```

Your price map (`int` to `Client`) would look like this:

```js
const price = {
    1: client1,
    2: client2
};
```

Now, you can use serialize it to json:

```
const json = JSON.stringify(price);
```

Or parse it from json:

```
const price = JSON.parse(json);
```

However, if you really want to use `Map`, here's a [tutorial](https://2ality.com/2015/08/es6-map-json.html) for it.